# Rational numbers with repeating decimals in binary

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers, binary

Is it possible to prove that there exists a rational number with repeating decimal digits in base-10 representation that isn't repeating in binary?

For example, $0.\overline{0011}_2$ is a binary representation of $0.2_{10}$ which contains repeating digits to the right of the decimal point.

I'm wondering if there exists some $A \in \mathbb{Q}$ in which $A_{10}$ contains repeating decimal digits, but $A_2$ doesn't.

I'm asking this out of curiosity, this is not homework.

Comment: Rational numbers are rational in any basis, so no.  Unless you are trying to distinguish between "repeating" and "terminating".

Comment: Do you mean an $A$ whose decimal expansion is non-terminating, but whose binary expansion terminates? If so, the answer is _no_. If the binary expansion terminates, $A$ can be written as a fraction whose denominator is a power of $2$, and in that case its decimal expansion will also terminate, since $2$ is a factor of $10$.

Comment: @lulu just to make sure, a non-terminating decimal is not necessarily repeating?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes that what I was trying to say.

Comment: @Kookie  Of course.  But "repeating" decimals, including the terming ones are precisely the rationals, so the basis doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, of course, a terminating decimal in base $b$ could also be considered as a repeating decimal with either repeating zeros or repeating $b-1$s. Subtract one from the last nonzero decimal place and then add repeating $b-1$s to the end to get the other non-obvious representation, generalizing the fact that $0.999...=1$ in base $10$. In case of a positive integer, just subtract one from the integer and then add a decimal point followed by repeating $b-1$s. Finally, for a negative integer, add one to the integer and then add a decimal point followed by repeating $b-1$s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "repeating" refers to "non-terminating", such numbers do not exist. Any non-repeating or terminating number in binary has the form $a/2^n$ for some integral $a,n$. Multiplying top and bottom by $5^n$ yields $5^na/10^n$, showing that the number is terminating in base 10 as well. Hence, by contraposition, any number repeating in decimal is also repeating in binary.

Comment: What makes this question and answer somewhat interesting is that there is an apparent asymmetry. There are some non-repeating decimal numbers which are repeating in binary, for example 0.1 decimal. This means 0.1 can't be precisely represented or stored using simple binary. However the converse is not true -- there are no non-repeating binary numbers which are repeating in decimal.